# Is there a way to smooth the mesh topology or mesh seamlessly to join these two mesh?

Tags: mesh, vertices, topology

Blender noob here, I downloaded a model to use it as a base, the original model has a squared head, I was trying to make it round as the reference image, my take was using a circular shape, cut it in half and extrude it but at the moment of joining both meshes with loop tools through help in my previous post, it did a great result but it's cutting a bit on sides. In scene 2; I did the result I was desiring but with a lot of tweaks but mesh isn't perfect and creates undesired crevice. I tried using smooth vertices but it ends flattening the mesh or modifying it.

I was wondering if there's a more efficient take in the result I want or a way to clean up the mesh from scene 2?

reference of model [image: reference of model]

what I did through loop tools but at the sides looks sharp [image: what I was trying to do with the two mesh]

my take, and then I merged these two shapes as previous image[image: original mesh with squared shape]

original model I downloaded, it is squary[image: desired result but with clean look]

This is what I could do by a lot of tweaking but at the middle in red theres this crevice, It's supposed to be smooth there[image]

[image]

I've multiple scenes if it helps to see better the problem[image]

Comment: Hello, I can't see the undesired crevices in the file you share: https://zupimages.net/up/23/22/6w3x.jpg  I can see bad shading but it's due to the Mark Sharp

Comment: hello! yeah, I mean in scene: ''desired result'', I've multiple scenes, in that scene at the middle there's a sharp crevice in the middle, it's supposed to be smooth there

Comment: The topology is not very good, rather than fixing problems on an object that has a bad topology, you should better begin with a good topology

Comment: oh ok, better topology would mean way less vertices?

Comment: in your case, yes, you can use much less vertices, also avoid this big ngon, unless it is coplanar with its adjacent faces, which is not the case here

Comment: still, there's a way to make work what I'm intending with that mesh? or there's not hope? currently I don't see myself being able to do that from zero, I lack the knowledge. now it's that I'm learning the basics of modeling. would you start off a primitive or with planes tracing the shape?

Comment: Try to redo the mesh with much less vertices, bevel the edges that need to stay sharp, give it a Subdivision Surface modifier to make the shape rounder, apply the modifier if necessary (but always keep a non-destructive version with the modifier unapplied), it will be a better idea than trying to fix a bad topology imho